# why can't i delete a row in table from javascript?

Tags: html, checkbox, input, event-handling, event-listener

I'm trying to build a table out from JavaScript, so far so good.
The main idea is that the last column will be a checkbox, and when it will be checked the row will delete. before i delete it, i need to know what was written in this row, so i'm checking the id. for some reason it doesn't work. can someone help me?
Thanks

This is the building function:

```
 function build(name){

   var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("alertsDiv");
   var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
   var tr;
   var i, j;


   table.style="width:90%; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; border: 1px   solid black; border-collapse: collapse";
   table.id = "tbAlerts";
   var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
   table.appendChild(tableBody);
   tableBody.id = "tbBody";

   //users is an array 
   for ( i=0; i< Users.length ; i++) {
     tr = document.createElement('TR');
     tr.id = name+" row";

     //alert("this is the tr id: " +tr.id);
     tableBody.appendChild(tr);

     //the time
     td = document.createElement('TD');
     var d = new Date();
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode( d.getHours() +":"+ d.getMinutes() +":"+ d.getSeconds() ));
     tr.appendChild(td);

     //severity
     td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("minor"));
     tr.appendChild(td);

     //alert
     var td = document.createElement('TD');
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name + " is dead"));
     tr.appendChild(td);

     //comments
     td = document.createElement('TD');
     var txtBox = document.createElement('INPUT');
     txtBox.type = 'text';
     txtBox.placeholder="comments";
     td.appendChild(txtBox);
     tr.appendChild(td);

     //Acknowledge - ***THIS IS THE IMPORTANT THING***
     td = document.createElement('TD');
     var newCheckBox = document.createElement('INPUT');
     newCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
     rowsNum++;
     newCheckBox.name=name;
     newCheckBox.addEventListener("CheckboxStateChange", cleanAlert, false);
     td.width='10px';
     td.appendChild(newCheckBox);
     tr.appendChild(td);
 }

myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

This is the delete function:

```
function cleanAlert(event) {
  var checkbox = event.target;
  var rowIndex;

  rowIndex = document.getElementById(checkbox.name + " row").rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("tbAlerts").deleteRow(rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you try debugging this code? Try to step through every statement on at a time. Check if every variable has a correct value, etc.

Comment: I tried to debug the code. the problem that it's works only for the first time. if i'm adding one row and delete it, then it's ok, but if I do it again he give me the right index, but do nothing

Comment: This seems valuable information, I would add this to your question. After you have deleted the row a first time, are you certain that the index in the delete function still matches the index of the row you want to delete?

Comment: Yes, I the rowIndex variable give me the currect index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your build function gets called, but
I gave every `checkbox` a unique name instead of the `name`-parameter of your `build()`function.
See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq7amedw/).

Notice the following line inside the `for`-loop:

```js
var localname = name + i;
```

I then replaced every occurence of the `name`-variable with the `localname`-variable.

I've also changed the eventListener to listen to "`click`" instead of "`CheckboxStateChange`".